# grep challenge - extract search pattern after searching any number of characters

Tags: regex, grep

Lets say I did this:

```
 echo stackoverflow > file
 grep sta[a-z]*w file
```

grep result is `stackoverflow`

But how do I get only original pattern `sta` & `w`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -oE 'sta|w'
```

or

```
grep -o 'sta\|w'
```

should give what you want. e.g:

```
kent$   echo "stakoverflow"|grep -oE 'sta|w'
sta
w
```

Comment: try to pipe the output to paste -s: `grep...|paste -s`

Comment: I am having problem with this one - `|` is used as OR and I need both hits so tried to use `[a-z]*`.

Comment: my commands work with your example. please add proper examples in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to generalize `sta` and `w`, then this version may be helpful:

```
echo stackoverflow > file
grep 'sta[a-z]*w' file | sed 's/\(sta\)[a-z]*\(w\)/\1 \2/'
```